# javascript inside php while loop

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

i have this code:

```
<?php
$i=5;
while($i > 0){
echo '
<table width="500px" border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>
    <button id="button">Show comments</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="comments" style="display:none;height:300px;width:100%;"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#button").toggle(
    function (){
        $("#button").text("Hide Comments");
        document.getElementById("comments").style.display="inline";
    },function (){
        $("#button").text("Show Comments");
        document.getElementById("comments").style.display="none";
    }
);
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
';

$i--;

}
?>
```

When the show comments button is clicked the comment box should show up. It works for the first one. But it doesn't work for the others.What's wrong?

Comment: your loops seems to output elements with identical ids... and that is invalid

Comment: What has the #show id?  Is that on the button? It should be either show-0, show-1, etc or a class of show.  Also, you need to specify the 2nd one goes with the 2nd bit of stuff, etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd just escape the php interpreter and print the HTML markup directly into the page. I'd also change the ids to classes, so we can more easily reuse them without quirky additional numbers.

```
<?php
$i=5;
while($i > 0):
?>
    <table width="500px" border="1">
       <tr>
          <td><button class="button" data-clicked="0">Show comments</button></td>
       </tr>
       <tr>
          <td class="comments" style="display:none;height:300px;width:100%;"></td>
       </tr>
    </table>
<?php
$i--;
endwhile;
?>
```

I don't know what `the element with an ID` of show is, but we'll just assume it was the button.

```
$(".button").click(function (){
    var $this = $(this);
    if(!$this.data('clicked')){
        $this.text("Hide Comments");
        $this.closest('table').find('.comments').css('display', 'inline');

        $this.data('clicked', 1);
    }else{
        $this.text("Show Comments");
        $this.closest('table').find('.comments').css('display', 'none');

        $this.data('clicked', 0);
    }

});
```

Don't print that javascript in a `while` loop in php, just include it in the head of the page, or in a separate file.

**Edit**

As indicated in a comment below,in jQuery 1.9 the `toggle` no longer works as you're intending to use it, as a work around, you can add a `data attribute` to the button, and check it each time we click.

```
<button class="button" data-clicked="0">
```

As you can see we've added the new `data-clicked` attribute.

In our JavaScript above, you can see that we've completely changed how it works. We perform our own `if/else` to check the `data-clicked` state.

Comment: using `toggle` in this way has been deprecated... just as an FYI.

Comment: @ahren thanks; I'd forgotten that. I think the above will work.

Answer (score 0):

It is generally good practice to separate code, markup and style declarations. As a matter of style, I prefer numbered IDs. I find they help with debugging. ymmv
I also like to animate changes so people can more easily follow a change.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Button Testing 1 2 3</title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <style>
            .comment {
                display: none;
                height: 0px;
                width: 500px;
            }
            td  {
                width: 500px;
                border: 1px solid #555;
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
<body>
<?
$j = 0;
while ($j < 5 ) {
?>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
        <button id="button_<?= $j ?>" class="button">Show comments</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="comment"><span id="comment_<?= $j ?>">J = <?= $j ?></span></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
<? 
    $j++;
} ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".button").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var j  = id.substr(id.indexOf('_') +1);

        if ($(this).hasClass('revealed')) {
            $(this).removeClass('revealed').text('Show Comments');
            $('#comment_'+j).removeClass('revealed').parent().animate({'height' : 0}, function(){$(this).css({'display': 'none'})});
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('revealed').text('Hide Comments');
            $('#comment_'+j).addClass('revealed').parent().css({'display': 'inline'}).animate({'height' : '300px'});
        }
    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```